# Updating Many Rows in Django

Tags: django, django-models

So I have a few models...

- User
- UserProfile
- UserJob (1-1 related name is job)
- Job (foreign key to user job)
- Location (job and user both have a location)

I need to update the user profile with three queries..

- Update the users who have been active in the last day and are at the same location as the job location
- Update the users UserJob relation who haven't been active in the last day or are not at the same locations as their job
- Delete UserJob if the UserJob value days_missed is 3

I know how I could do this just be selecting all the users with a job and iterating through but this seems way too labour intensive with X amount of users. Is there a simple way like using a UPDATE ... WHERE query or something.

I was thinking of something like this maybe?:

```
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
users = User.objects.filter(
    job__isnull = False,
    location = job__job__location,
    profile__last_online__gte = yesterday
)
```

The problem is that you cannot use a field for the job__job__location bit

Answer (score 1):

You can only update fields on the model you are updating, so your query has to be on the `UserJob` object. I don't have the exact relations without your model definitions, but this or something close should work:

```
UserJob.objects.filter(
    user__location = F('job__location'),
    user__profile__last_online__gte = yesterday
).update(
    days_worked = F('days_worked') + 1,
    points = F('points') + 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should solve your problem:

Updating multiple objects at once:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

F expression: Refer to model values in the WHERE clause:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters